# Shortcut syntax for boost function_input_iterator range

Tags: c++, boost

I am wondering if there is a shortcut syntax for this sort of code:

```
#include <boost/iterator/function_input_iterator.hpp>
#include <boost/range.hpp>

int main() {
    std::function<int (int)> f = [](int i) -> int {
       // some logic, return int
    };
    auto r = boost::make_iterator_range(boost::make_function_input_iterator(f, 0), boost::make_function_input_iterator(f, 10));
    return 0;
}
```

Two notes:

- I couldn't use `auto f = [](int i) ->int {...};` as this causes:

`error: no type named 'result_type' in 'struct main()::<lambda(int)>'`

using std::function fixes it for some reason.

- Also I can't pass `f` as temporary inline ie `boost::make_function_input_iterator([](int i) ->int {...}, ...` as that function takes f by reference.

Ideally I'd like to be able to do:

`make_function_input_range(0, 10, [](int i)->int {...});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a trivial wrapper that adds the typedef:

```
template <typename F>
struct ref_wrap : std::reference_wrapper<F> {
    typedef decltype(std::declval<F>()() result_type;
    ref_wrap(F& f) : std::reference_wrapper<F>(f) {}
};
```

> PS. *I use a reference wrapper to stay with `function_input_iterator`'s requirements, which already require the function to be an lvalue reference. You could leave this behind now, actually, since we return the function wrapper as well as the range, see below*

Next up, have a helper that returns a tuple of that wrapper and the iterator-range built on it:

```
template <typename F>
struct input_function_range_wrapper {
    struct ref_wrap : std::reference_wrapper<F> {
        typedef decltype(std::declval<F>()()) result_type;
        ref_wrap(F& f) : std::reference_wrapper<F>(f) {}
    } wrap;

    using It = boost::function_input_iterator<ref_wrap, int>;
    boost::iterator_range<It> range;

    template <typename V>
    input_function_range_wrapper(F& f, V a, V b) : wrap(f), range(It(wrap, a), It(wrap, b))
    { }
};
```

To make using it convenient, lets move it into a detail namespace and add a factory function:

```
template <typename F, typename V = int>
auto make_input_function_range(F& f, V a, V b) {
    return detail::input_function_range_wrapper<F>(f, a, b);
}
```

Now to really top it off, we add ADL-enabled `begin` and `end` calls and PRONTO, we can use c++'s ranged-for on it:

```
int main() {
    auto f = [i=1]() mutable { return i*=2; };

    for (auto v : make_input_function_range(f, 0, 10)) {
        std::cout << v << " ";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
2 4 8 16 32 64 128 256 512 1024
```

---

### FULL DEMO

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0f9bb78891c86a98)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/iterator/function_input_iterator.hpp>
#include <boost/range.hpp>

namespace detail {

    template <typename F>
    struct input_function_range_wrapper {
        struct ref_wrap : std::reference_wrapper<F> {
            typedef decltype(std::declval<F>()(/*std::declval<V>()*/)) result_type;
            ref_wrap(F& f) : std::reference_wrapper<F>(f) {}
        } wrap;

        using It = boost::function_input_iterator<ref_wrap, int>;
        boost::iterator_range<It> range;

        template <typename V>
        input_function_range_wrapper(F& f, V a, V b) : wrap(f), range(It(wrap, a), It(wrap, b))
        { }
    };

    template <typename... Ts>
        auto begin(input_function_range_wrapper<Ts...>& r)       { return r.range.begin(); }
    template <typename ... Ts>
        auto begin(input_function_range_wrapper<Ts...> const& r) { return r.range.begin(); }
    template <typename ... Ts>
        auto end  (input_function_range_wrapper<Ts...>& r)       { return r.range.end  (); }
    template <typename ... Ts>
        auto end  (input_function_range_wrapper<Ts...> const& r) { return r.range.end  (); }
}

template <typename F, typename V = int>
auto make_input_function_range(F& f, V a, V b) {
    return detail::input_function_range_wrapper<F>(f, a, b);
}

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    auto f = [i=1]() mutable { return i*=2; };

    for (auto v : make_input_function_range(f, 0, 10)) {
        std::cout << v << " ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the `error: no type named 'result_type'`, refer to this [bug](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/9631).

`make_function_input_range` is trivial to write, but this cannot be used with plain lambdas, because of the mentioned bug:

```
template<class T>
auto make_function_input_range(std::size_t begin, std::size_t end, T& f) {
    return boost::make_iterator_range(
        boost::make_function_input_iterator(f, begin),
        boost::make_function_input_iterator(f, end));
}
```

To work around the bug, I would create a small helper type that defines the required `result_type`, rather than use the type-erasing `std::function`:

```
template<class T>
struct fun_wrapper {
    T f;

    using result_type = typename boost::function_types::result_type<T>;
    template<class... Args>
    result_type operator() (Args&&... args) const {
        return f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

template<class T>
auto make_fun_wrapper(T&& f) {
    return fun_wrapper<T>{std::forward<T>(f)};
}

int main() {
    auto wrapped_f = make_fun_wrapper([](int i)->int {/*...*/});
    auto range = make_function_input_range(0, 10, wrapped_f);
}
```

Comment: I think BOOST enables USE_DECLTYPE depending on your compiler. And there's also USE_DECLTYPE_WITH_TR1_FALLBACK

Comment: @sehe apparently, USE_DECLTYPE doesn't even help here (should have tested), because [`make_function_input_iterator` doesn't even use it](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/9631).

Comment: The edit has UB because function_input_iterator stores a reference to the function IIRC

Comment: Mmm. My memory might be hazy on this. Somehow I recall running into this, but looking at the code it doesn't look like it's UB now - 1.60.0+. I'd need to spend more time to check it though.

Comment: @sehe seems UB to me. [`function_input_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/boost/iterator/function_input_iterator.hpp) does appear to take the function by reference and store the function by a pointer. I decided to move the wrapper outside `make_function_input_range` and take the function by reference. Not as nice since, but I think it's correct, and has simple implementation.

Comment: Did you see how my answer worked around the lifetime issue? Really that wrapper doesn't even have to store a reference anymore. That makes boost's iterator more useful IMO

Comment: @sehe yeah, I see your solution. I like it more than mine.